# How to find out what my live stream URL is?

Tags: url, streaming, live, rtmp

I am trying to stream from obs or similar to maybe restream, but I also want to send the feed to a custom RTMP player on my site, it's asking for the Live Streaming URL. How can I find that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe obs asks you to connect to a streaming platform (I think this is what you meant by "restream"). Depending on the platform you are streaming to (Twitch, Youtube, etc), then you would need to get the URL from that site. Connect to one of these first and it should give you a URL. I think YouTube requires 24 hours to enable live streaming.

If you can stream directly to your website I am not aware of it. Reason being, in most cases you have a dynamic IP or port that is not open for your website to view the original stream from your Obs software/computer.

Comment: ok so i am using a RTMP player that can receive live stream test, it wants the live streaming url... thats what i am not sure how to obtain. i know how to connect obs to something like restream, not by using live stream url. for example https://www.hlstester.com/embed-player-generator.php

Comment: It's possible i'm not understanding something here as well. But when I hear live stream I assume it is a direct feed of some video/music stream. 

For the case of your website you may consider using a third party as I mentioned.

 After looking at the link you sent try putting your stream from Youtube/twitch in the url. It would end up looking like this. 

```<iframe src="https://youtube.com/yourstreamuri" width="633" height="333" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>```

The only thing that site seems to be doing is creating html for a stream.